# HTML5 <animate> Tag not working in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

After learning some HTML basics I tried to make this animation, which works in my Firefox browser.
Now I wonder why it doesn't work on my IE 11 as excepted.
It shows everything but it doesn't play the animation.
Here's the HTML-Text:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 Circle Test</title>
<style>
svg{
 vertical-align:top;
 border:5px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
circle{
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<svg width="1000" height="1000">
<circle cx="0" cy="0" r="50" fill="yellow" stroke="black">
<animate attributeName="cx" from="-50" to="1100" dur="5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
<animate attributeName="cy" from="100" to="700" dur="5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
<animate attributeName="r" from="50" to="100" dur="5s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
<circle/>
</body>
</html>
```

Another thing: I tried it out without having the admin rights and can't access many properties of IE, could it be that IE is blocking something that I have to change first?
Since I'm new to HTML I would also appreciate if someone could give me useful hints to these kinds of problems because, for example, I can't find the animate tag in w3schools in the HTML Element Reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that tag not supported in IE. See link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate#Browser_compatibility